# Python 2.7 sqlite3 how to determine empty field

Tags: sqlite

I'm accessing an sqlite3 with a Python script, using

```
input_data = None
connection = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
db = connection.cursor()
read_string = 'select viewer_id, email, device_group, created_date, path_found, analyzed from ' + db_table + ' where analyzed < ' + str(cfg_history_number_of_days) + ';'
db.execute(read_string)
input_data = db.fetchall()
connection.close()
```

and this works great when there's data in the 'analyze' field. When 'analyze' s empty, the script considers the field to have a value much greater than my string value, and this test fails. How can I change my script so that I can determine whether the field is blank in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any comparison with NULL fails. To make NULL values behave as if they were a small string, [replace](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull) them with a small string:

```sql
SELECT ... FROM db_table WHERE ifnull(analyzed, '') < ...;
```

Comment: Thanks...that worked perfectly, with one exception: I had to put quotes around the ?, making the line

SELECT ... FROM db_table WHERE ifnull(analyzed, 0) < ‘?’;

because my field is a text field. But since you gave the precise solution for me, I’m marking it THE solution.
Thanks!

Comment: Please note that `str(...)` results in an unquoted value, which is interpreted by SQL as a number. Apparently, the column's [affinity](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity) helps, but you should use the correct type in comparisons.

Comment: Yes, the analyzed value is an integer, so the str(...) value will also be an integer, since there are no quotes, and therefore the types match. Thanks!